# Project my screen of my Nexus One

Tags: nexus-one, screen-sharing

I have a Nexus One, I would like to know if there is any way for me to project my screen content to my large screen TV?

Nexus One does not come with a hdmi port.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

By "project", do you mean "play video"? Because that might be a bit of a challenge, depending on your network and (phone) CPU.

To just get screens/presentations, you could connect a laptop to your TV and a VNC server on your phone.

If you do want to play media files, and you have a DLNA client (Xbox 360, PS3, one of the million media boxes like Roku) connected, you can install a DLNA server on your Android (search Market - there are plenty) and stream media.

Plenty of the latest TVs even have a DLNA client built in.